# rotate a sublayer in xcode

Tags: xcode, rotation

It's been a while, as I was hospitalized for 3 months after a motorcycle accident.
So I just got to renew my apple programming subscription :-)

I have another question that has been on my mind for quite some time.
In my iPad application I draw a triangle in the center of an iPad like this:

```
- (void)initTriangle
{
CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;

// draw triangle (TRIANGLE)
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path,NULL, 0.5*screenWidth, 0.5*screenHeight-25);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0.5*screenWidth-25, 0.5*screenHeight+25);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0.5*screenWidth+25, 0.5*screenHeight+25);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0.5*screenWidth, 0.5*screenHeight-25);

CAShapeLayer *triangle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[triangle setPath:path];
[triangle setFillColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[[[self view] layer] addSublayer:triangle];

CGPathRelease(path);
}
```

And I call this from my viewDidLoad like this:

```
[self initTriangle];
```

Now I'm trying to rotate this triangle with the rotation of my iPad around Z-Axis while laying flat on the table. I have a function that gives me the yaw readings in float and I'm calling my
    -(void)updateTriangleWithYaw:(float)yaw
method, but I don't know what to exactly put in there to make it rotate.

here is what my method looks like so far:

```
-(void)updateTriangleWithYaw:(float)yaw
{
CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;

NSLog(@"YAW: %f", yaw);
Z += 2 * yaw;
Z *= 0.8;

CGFloat newR = R + 10 * yaw;

self.triangle.frame = CGRectMake(0.5*screenWidth, 0.5*screenHeight, newR, newR);
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks and be safe guys!!

Answer (score 0):

You should set the layer's `affineTransform`.  You can apply a rotation transform like:

```
[self.triangle setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(yaw)];
```

This method, `setAffineTransform` is a convenience to set the `transform` property of the layer, which is a more general type of transform `CATransform3D`.  You can also set the `transform` of the layer directly, and if you want to do that you can make a rotation about the z-axis like:

```
self.triangle.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(yaw, 0, 0, 1);
```

In this case the first argument is the angle (in radians) and the last three arguments specify the axis of rotation.

Note that you should not assign or depend on the value of the `frame` property of a layer whose transform is not the identity (`CGAffineTransformIdentity`).  When you use the transform property you should set the size and position of your layer by assigning the layer's `center` and `bounds` properties, and similarly you should read the `center` and `bounds` when you want to find out information about the layer's position and size.

Comment: Hey Aaron, thanks for the reply! I'm not sure how to apply the code snippet provided. I copied it into my method updateTriangleWithYaw but it doesn't seem to have any effect on my triangle :-/ Any ideas?

Comment: No effect at all, huh?  Are you sure self.triangle is assigned?  I see you create a triangle shape layer in initTriangle, but I don't see you assign it to self.triangle.  (Also it just occurred to me that your triangle is a layer, not a view, so I'll need to revise my answer slightly, but it's basically going to be the same idea.)

Comment: That throws an error: // Assigning to 'CGAffineTransform' (aka 'struct CGAffinrTransform') from incompatible type 'CATransform3D' (aka 'struct CAtransform3D')

Comment: @Studiologe: It sounds like you're trying to pass `CATransform3DMakeRotation(yaw, 0, 0, 1)` to the `setAffineTransform` method.  If you use `setAffineTransform` you need to pass a `CGAffineTransform`, such as is returned by `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`.  The two bits of sample code I posted have the same effect, but you can't mix and match the arguments between them.  You must pass an affine transform to `setAffineTransform` *or* assign a `CATransform3D` to `triangle.transform`.

Comment: Hi
I still couldn't get it to work. Is there maybe another way to achieve this? I think I need to take a different approach, but have been trying all morning now and also trying to find something online, but wasn't able to achieve anything.
Please someone help out. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68602/discussion-between-aaron-golden-and-studiologe).